# JS shorterhand conditional?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following shorthand conditional in JS/jQuery:

```
var delay = $(this).data("delay") ? $(this).data("delay") : options.delay;
```

If the element has a `data-delay` attribute use that value, otherwise get the value from `options.delay`.

It seems excessive using `$(this).data("delay")` two times in the shorthand conditional. Is there a better way to do it?

Would `var delay = $(this).data("delay") || options.delay;` be a good solution? I am not sure if all browser supports it.

Comment: You can use `truthy || options.prop`

Comment: "*I am not sure if all browser supports it.*" only every browser which supports JavaScript. I think it's safe to say you shouldn't care about the rest.

Comment: Any of those wouldn't work as expected, if `delay` can be zero. Go with nullish coalescing operator as Svinjica has answered, or If you're worried about browser support, use an `if..else` instead, don't minify the developement code, a minifier will minify the production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can use Nullish Coalescing Operator.
A nullish value is a value that is either null or undefined.

So, you can use something like this:

```
var delay = $(this).data("delay") ?? options.delay;
```

You can read more about it on this page:
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-nullish-coalescing-operator/

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it has good browser support.

Comment: Great, if the answer suits your need then you can accept it to mark it as resolved :)